# Interactive Shiny app with R - Hovering over points and displaying info

Tags: r, ggplot2, web-applications, shiny

I am working in R to create a Shiny App.

Here is the example data I'm working with:

```
data <- data.frame("name" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                   "code_name" = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
                   "x" = c(.13, .64, .82, .39, .51, .03),
                   "y" = c(.62, .94, .10, .24, .20, .84))
```

I'm trying to have a Shiny App that allows users to select one of the options from column `name`, display a scatterplot of the `x` and `y` values, and also print the value from the `code_name` column under the plot when you hover your mouse near a certain point.

Here is the code for `ui`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "x",
                  label = "Choose a Letter:",
                  choices = levels(data$name),
                  selected = "A")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot",
                 hover = hoverOpts(id ="plot_hover")),
      verbatimTextOutput("hover_info")
    )
  )
)
```

Here is the code for `server`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    data %>%
      filter(name == input$x) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point() +
      xlim(c(0, 1)) +
      ylim(c(0, 1))
    })

  output$hover_info <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$plot_hover)){
      hover = input$plot_hover
      dist = sqrt((hover$x-data$x)^2 + (hover$y-data$y)^2)
      cat("Name\n")
      if(min(dist) < 3)
        data$code_name[which.min(dist)]
    }
  })
}
```

Then, of course:

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The first output object, `output$scatterplot`, works as desired. It is a scatterplot of the `x` and `y` values for observations where `data$name` is the selected value from `input$x`.

The problem is with the second object, `output$hover_info`. What I want is the text box result from `renderPrint` to *only* print `code_name` for observations where `data$name == input$x`. The way it is now, if I select "A" from the drop-down menu, and hover over one of the plotted points, it correctly prints that point's `code_name` below the plot. However, if I hover over a random spot that is near neither point, it will pick up the location of one of the other `name` option points, and display that observation's `code_name`.

For example, if you run the code as-is (where `name == "A"` is the default selection in the drop-down), and hover your mouse near the coordinate x = 0.5, y = 0.5, it will print `B2` below the plot. I want to avoid this. It's not a big deal here, where there are only 2 data points per name selection, but when using this same framework with larger data sets, it gets very messy.

I've been trying to include some type of `filter` call in the `output$hover_info` object in order for it to only consider observations defined through the drop-down menu, but get an error every time I try that.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally recommend an approach in which you create a `reactive` object for any kind of user manipulation of your data, and then refer to that `reactive` object in your `render*` call. I find it less constraining than trying to get everything done within the `render*` call, it's easier to debug, and to get a better understanding of how the reactivity of your data is supposed to work.

Here I've created a `filtered_data` reactive object that gets filtered based on the drop down, and then it gets referred further down. The reason why your code wasn't working properly is because your `dist` calculation was done for the full data set, not the filtered data set. Also, I think your threshold of 3 was too wide, so I changed it to 0.3 here.

Finally, note the usage of `req()` instead of `if(!is.null())`, which is cleaner and is more consistent in terms of when we want it to display the data.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    filter(data, name == input$x)
  })

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point() +
      xlim(c(0, 1)) +
      ylim(c(0, 1))
  })

  displayed_text <- reactive({
    req(input$plot_hover)
    hover <- input$plot_hover
    dist <- sqrt((hover$x - filtered_data()$x)^2 + (hover$y - filtered_data()$y)^2)

    if(min(dist) < 0.3) {
      filtered_data()$code_name[which.min(dist)]
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })

  output$hover_info <- renderPrint({
    req(displayed_text())

      cat("Name\n")
      displayed_text()
  })
}
```

Let me know if this is in line with what you were looking for.

Comment: great solution! The creation of the reactive objects acheived exactly what I was looking for - applying the filter I used in my ggplot call to other objects. I hadn't learned about reactive objects yet, so this was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Phil, if I wanted to make it so the text that pops up when I hover over a point would not only include code_name, but code_name as well as a value from a different column - how would I go about that? I tried adding a line under the filtered_data()$code_name[which.min(dist)], with the same syntax, just referencing a different column in the filtered_data() object (like filtered_data()$new_col[which.min(dist)] ... and it ended up only printing the second bit I defined (no longer printed the code_name value). How would I get it to display multiple values when hovering?

Comment: I would save `filtered_data()$code_name[which.min(dist)]` into a new object (say, `code_name_min`) and save `filtered_data()$new_col[which.min(dist)]` into another object (say `new_col_min`), then add `paste(code_name_min, new_col_min)` as the last line in the `displayed_text` reactive call.

Comment: The reason why you got the 2nd value only to show up is because the `reactive` function acts the same as when you create a custom function, in that it returns whatever you have it run last.